# how to change image onclick for few seconds using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, onclick

i have a an image section where onclick i want to change it for few seconds and make it back to original image after few seconds, i did the following code:

```html
<img src="contacticons.jpg" usemap="#image-map" id="imgName">
<a onclick="document.getElementById('imgName').src='../newImgSrc.jpg';"></a>
```

can anyone please tell me how to change it for few seconds and take it back to original image, thanks in advance

Comment: Inline `on*` handlers should never be used. Just like you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes. JS, CSS should in one place only and those are the respective tags or files. Use [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Don't use `<a>` tags (**Anchor**) if you actually need a `<button type="button">`. Anchors are for navigating or anchoring, not for triggering UX, UI changes, or styling stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ChangeImage()
{
  var originalImage = $("#imgName").attr("src");
  var changeImage = $("#imgName").data("changeimage");
  $("#imgName").attr("src",changeImage);  
  setTimeout(function(){
  $("#imgName").attr("src",originalImage);
  }, 1000);

  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498598457418-36ef20772bb9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" usemap="#image-map"  id="imgName" height="50"
data-changeimage="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg">

<a onclick="ChangeImage()">change</a>
```

Comment: i dont want to change image every few seconds, i just want to display an image onclick and after few seconds take it back to original image

Comment: then use setTimeout() function to take it back to original image after few seconds.

Comment: I added full answer here.Check it out & let me know if you want any other details.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Inline `on*` handlers should never be used. Just like you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes. JS, CSS should in one place only and those are the respective tags or files. Use [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Cache your selectors Object instances. Querying the DOM to lookup for a `$("#imgName")` multiple times is a waste of resource.

Comment: This answer has the same issue like @meet's answer. On multiple clicks - the timteouts are stacked one on the other and will all resolve in order without clearing.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan actually my on click is inside the image, using map tag, so i guess multiple clicks are not possible

Comment: @ZNO in the example above: do a quick double-click. And you'll see the bug.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i saw that bro, but in mine the onclick is inside the original image, so when user clicks on the image it changes, he cant do a multiple click

Answer (score 0):

No need using id, just call a function using the onclick event.

```js
function changeImg(objImg, newSrc) {
  const originalSrc = objImg.getAttribute('src');
  const originalSrcBase = objImg.getAttribute('data-original-src');
  if (!originalSrcBase) {
    objImg.setAttribute('data-original-src', originalSrc)
  }
  if (originalSrc !== originalSrcBase) {
    return;
  }
  objImg.setAttribute('src', newSrc);

  setTimeout(() => {
    objImg.setAttribute('src', originalSrc);
  },1000);
}
```

```html
<img onclick="changeImg(this, 'https://nodejs.org/static/images/logo.svg');"
      src="https://nodejs.org/static/images/openjs_foundation-logo.svg" />
```

Comment: Inline `on*` handlers should never be used. Just like you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes. JS, CSS should in one place only and those are the respective tags or files. Use [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - this is a simple example to show him the concept and basic idea

Comment: On multiple clicks you'll have a nice bug. Same issue as all the other answers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - yup. I've edit the code to handle this as well.